# How to display a popup message after an item is saved from a custom new form

Tags: sharepoint-designer, jquery

I have a custome form i built from a list using SharePoint Designer.
I would like a message to popup after the user has clicked the save button.
I have played arounf with presaveaction but no luck.
I don't want to redirect to a new page but e.g just an alert ot a jquery pop message to load.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5):

PreSaveAction should work for you, something along the lines of this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function PreSaveAction() {
 alert('Thank you for the submission');
 return true;
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Nope i want the popup to appear after the record has been added.
Tried that before and when i use ur code every time i click on Save button i get the alert

Comment: For that, I think you'd need some sort of event receiver.  PreSaveAction does processing before the item is committed to the database.

Comment: Worked great for me. Thanks for providing this solution!

Answer (score 3):

try the Notify object

```
var  notifyId = null;
function Notify(msg, sec) {
  notifyId = SP.UI.Notify.addNotification(msg, true);

  setTimeout(function () {
    SP.UI.Notify.removeNotification(notifyId);
    notifyId = '';
  }, (sec == null ? 1500 : sec));
}
```

Comment: the above code didn't work for me.Do I need to add the  sp.js reference just like jQuery and spservices.js file ? on top of my Content Editor web part?

Comment: try this one in your code Notify('This is a test...',1000); , it should work.
But I did noticed that after you change to 100 it won't come up

Comment: it worked. But I am not able to mark your reply as answer.Can you tell how to mark?